# Close stream node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am not able to close a stream in node.js this is my code

```
        var inp = fs.createReadStream("a/b/c/"+ Name);
        var out = fs.createWriteStream("a/b/c/"+ Name);
        inp.pipe(out);
            inp.close( function(err){
              if (err){
                console.log(err);
              } else {
              inp.unpipe(out);
              socket.emit('Done',{'Name':name});
              console.log('There will be no more data.');
              }
            });
```

Then i have this function further down in my code that deletes the directory the directory of inp

```
var fse = require("fs-extra");
fse.emptyDir("a/b/c/", function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("doneaaaa")
    fse.remove("a/b/c",function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('doneaswell');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and i get this error !!

```
doneaaaa
{ [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'a/b/c/.nfs000000002ab5000d00000072']
  errno: -16,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'a/b/c/.nfs000000002ab5000d00000072' }
```

Which means the stream is still open !

.nfs file is created while streaming right , but shouldn't file delete once the stream is closed ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't see you calling `unlink` // `unlinkSync` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback Also, what is `fse` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis  Sorry about that edited the question var fse = require ('fs-extra'); i tried unlink as well from the standard fs module ended the with same problems

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the callback to close to be invoked before you do a remove/unlock operation. From the samples you provided it doesn't look like this is the case.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit please ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Node.js runs async, which means that the deletion of the directory occours during the stream. Instead try putting the deletion inside of the callback so it occours after:

```
var inp = fs.createReadStream("a/b/c/"+ Name);
var out = fs.createWriteStream("a/b/c/"+ Name);
inp.pipe(out);
inp.close( function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    inp.unpipe(out);
    socket.emit('Done',{'Name':name});
    console.log('There will be no more data.');
  }

  var fse = require("fs-extra");
  fse.emptyDir("a/b/c/", function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("doneaaaa");
      fse.remove("a/b/c",function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('doneaswell');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

You were also missing a semicolon on one line which I added in this code as well :)

Comment: I will give it a try i need to remodel my whole upload module now.
Thank you, will post back with results!

Comment: @vic-3 You're welcome :) If it works mark this answer as accepted so that it's no longer unanswered :)